# Login failed for user sa, Error 18456

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, authentication, errors

I have just installed `SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition`. I started SQL Server instance on Configuration Manager, with Log on as `LocalSystem` feature, because it is the only option, which isn't caused several error message during instance starting. So after that I've started Management Studio, but it gives error above, when I would like to authenticate `SQL Server Authentication` method. I have created this user during installation.

Why couldn't connect to it?
`Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8. and State 5`. `State 5` is for Windows authentication, `state 8` is for sa user. I type password correctly, I have tried it several times.
Maybe `Log on as` setting should be the problem?

Comment: Have you check  https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: Yes, I have read this, but there is no solution in it for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure we're not mixing things, you do not create the SA login. You either enable using it by enabling mixed mode authentication (and provide a password) or not if you choose Windows integrated auth.

If you did select mixed mode and provided a password but cannot login using SA then you probably mistyped the password twice but didn't notice it (or maybe the SHIFT key was stuck at the time).

Try the Windows auth option when logging in via SSMS and see if that works. If that fails too and you did not add any other user to the sysadmin role during setup, you can create a new login and add it to sysadmin role or just reset SA password. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.120).aspx